# Mapping items in an array

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Hoping this is a nice easy one, but I just can't see how to do it.

I am wanting to with rego map items in an array to a cleaner version. For example from the data below

```
data = [
  {
    "some": "value",
    "another": "mvalue",
    "dont": "want"
  },
  {
    "some": "value1",
    "another": "mvalue1",
    "dont": "want1"
  },
  {
    "some": "value2",
    "another": "mvalue2",
    "dont": "want2"
  }
]
```

I want to turn data into

```
result = [
  {
    "some": "value",
    "another": "mvalue"
  },
  {
    "some": "value1",
    "another": "mvalue1"
  },
  {
    "some": "value2",
    "another": "mvalue2"
  }
]
```

The two closest I think I've got is

```
result1 = cleaned {
    cleaned := {d | 
        d := {
            "some": data[_].some,
            "another": data[_].another
        }
    }
}

result2 = cleaned {
    d := data[_]
    cleaned := {
        "some": p.some,
        "another": p.another
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; If the fields are static and you can easily enumerate them, both of your solutions is *almost* correct (see below for explanation of why they are incorrect.) Here's the right way to do that:

```
result = [
  mapped |
    original := data[_]
    mapped := {"some": original["some"], "another": original.another}
]
```

A slightly more elegant option is to define the fields to include or exclude like in @eephillip's example. For instance:

```
result = [
  mapped |
    original := data[_]
    mapped := {k: v |
      some k
      v := original[k]
      not exclude[k]}
]

exclude = {"dont", "dont2"}  # defines a SET of keys to exclude
```

Of course you could generalize it even more by making the inner comprehension invoke a function that implements other filters.

Here's an interactive example: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/P6wPd3rudJ

---

Two notes about the original solution.

## 1. `result1` does not iterate over `data` correctly

```
{d | 
  d := {
    "some": data[_].some,        # problem: _ is a different variable in each expression
    "another": data[_].another
  }
}
```

Conceptually each occurrence of `_` is a *unique* variable. If you explicitly declare the variables, the problem is more obvious:

```
# note: this is still wrong
{d | 
  some i, j
  d := {
    "some": data[i]["some"],
    "another": data[j].another
  }
}
```

If you run this, you'll discover that it produces a cross-product (which is not what you want). You want the "some" and "another" fields to be selected from *the same* object like this:

```
{d | 
  some i
  d := {
    "some": data[i]["some"],
    "another": data[i].another
  }
}
```

Of course, coming up with unique variable names can be a pain, so you can use `_`. Just do not mistake multiple `_` variables as referring to the same value. We can rewrite the statement to use `_` as follows:

```
{d | 
  obj := data[_]
  d := {
    "some": obj["some"],
    "another": obj.another
  }
}
```

### `result2` is close but may assign multiple values (which should be avoided)

```
result2 = cleaned {
    d := data[_]
    cleaned := {               # problem: there could be multiple values for 'cleaned'
        "some": d["some"],
        "another": d.another
    }
}
```

Rules of the form `NAME = VALUE { BODY }` assign `VALUE` to `NAME` if the statements in `BODY` are satisfied. If you omit `BODY`, i.e., you write `NAME = VALUE`, then `BODY` defaults to `true` (which is always satisfied.)

In your above example:

- `NAME` is `result2`
- `VALUE` is `cleaned`
- `BODY` is `d := data[_]; cleaned := {...}`

In Rego, we call these rules ["complete rules"](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#rules). Complete rules are just IF-THEN statements that assign a single value to a variable. The "IF" portion is the rule body and the "THEN" portion is the assignment. You should avoid writing rules that may assign MULTIPLE values to the same variable because that may result in an evaluation time error. For example:

```
# do not do this
result = v { 
   v := data[_]   # if 'data' is [1,2,3] then what is the value of 'result'? Hint: There is more than one answer.
}
```

If you want to assign MULTIPLE values to a variable then you can define a ["partial rule"](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#partial-rules) For example:

```
result[v] {       # result is a SET.
   v := data[_]
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation. I had tried result 1 using a named value, which didn't help, but the setting the intermediate value (`original` in yours is the key). Cheers.

Comment: The elegant option and @eephillips answer are also good for if the keys in the objects are optional.

Answer (score 1):

What about performing a rejection of the key name during the comprehensions? 
Probably a more elegant way to do this, but might be helpful.

```
package play

reject(key) = result {
    remove := [ "dont", "someotherthing" ]
    result :=  key == remove[_]
}

result = d {
    d := [ obj | 
           val := input.data[_]; 
           obj := { k: v | 
                    v := val[k] 
                    not reject(k)
                  }
          ] 
 }
```

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/1A3DNLiNfj

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good for if you want to remove specific keys.